# Python-compatible distributed messaging/task system (like Celery) that uses domain sockets

Tags: python, message-queue, celery, task-queue, unix-socket

Is there anything like Celery that works with unix domain sockets? My current host (dreamhost) forbids the running of servers that listen on IP sockets, so I need something that will work with domain sockets.

Obviously, easier solutions are preferred, but any message queuing software with a python client library and domain socket support will do me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely have a look at [zeromq python bindings](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/Python/), which are compatible with domain sockets.